# xcode copy/paste

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, copy, paste

How can I copy the text from a textfield?

Comment: Be clearer about what you're trying to do.

Comment: im trying to make a custom keyboard, but i cant find the right code.. so i will try with copy/paste

Comment: What is your target: Mac OS or iOS?

Comment: cmd+c / cmd+v works fine in Xcode

Comment: yh i know... but i mean copy/paste codes:)

Comment: eg.  insted of  numberr.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.f.", [numberr.text floatValue]];  because then it delete the dot:(

Comment: so maybe you should choose a better title, choose better tags and write a better question. I still don't know what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *copy = textfield.text;
```

Answer (score 2):

try:
`clipboard.copy(textfield.text)`